# Laravel observer events not showing all the attributes

Tags: laravel, events, eloquent

I have an observer with 2 events

```php
class OrderObserver
{
    public function created($model)
    {     
        Log::alert("observer" , [$model]);      
    }
    
    public function updated($model)
    {
        Log::alert("observer" , [$model]);        
    }
}
```

but in the created event i get less attributes for example i dont get **status**, **id** etc. what am i doing wrong?

this is the output of the logs

log for created

```
[2021-10-25 17:22:39] local.ALERT: observer [{"App\\Models\\Order":{"customer_id":"1","vat":"5","payment_option":"Pay Later","created_by":5,"updated_by":5,"updated_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z","created_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z","id":61,"order_number":"6100P66C","sub_total":"0.00","discount_in_money":"0.00","vat_in_money":"0.00","total_price":"0.00","products":[]}}]
```

log for updated

```
[2021-10-25 17:25:23] local.ALERT: observer [{"App\\Models\\Order":{"id":61,"address":null,"status":"Delivered","discount_type":null,"discount_amount":null,"vat":"5.00","payment_option":"Pay Later","order_mode":"pos","customer_id":1,"created_by":5,"updated_by":5,"created_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-25T17:25:23.000000Z","order_number":"6100P66C","payment_received":1,"sub_total":"24.98","discount_in_money":"0.00","vat_in_money":"1.25","total_price":"26.23","products":[{"id":1,"name":"Men's Shirt","image":null,"description":"All kinds of men's shirts are washed, dry cleaned and treated according to the category with different standards for each type of shirt","price":"9.99","is_package":0,"is_active":1,"product_category_id":1,"created_by":1,"updated_by":1,"created_at":"2021-07-03T13:28:15.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-03T13:28:15.000000Z","pivot":{"order_id":61,"product_id":1,"quantity":2,"price":"9.99","created_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z"}},{"id":2,"name":"Men's Trousers","image":null,"description":"All kinds of men's trousers are washed, dry cleaned and treated according to the category with different standards for each type of trousers","price":"5.00","is_package":0,"is_active":1,"product_category_id":1,"created_by":1,"updated_by":1,"created_at":"2021-07-03T13:41:38.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-03T13:41:38.000000Z","pivot":{"order_id":61,"product_id":2,"quantity":1,"price":"5.00","created_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-10-25T17:22:39.000000Z"}}]}}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`created` shows you the state of the Model as it was inserted in the database. Fields that have default values are not present at this point.

`updated` shows you the state of the Model after it's been inserted and fetched from the database. All those fields are now present.